# How do I compute a new variable using data from other respondents in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have a set of data from a questionnaire that asks each participant to nominate someone and then rate that person on several talents. The variables that pertains to this is:

An ID for the participant (id)

The ID for the person who was nominated (nomid)

A set of questions about the nominee on a 0-7 scale (q1 - q10)

An average of q1 - q10 (qmean)

How would I format a syntax command that computes a new variable that is equal to the average of the other participants' qmeans if they nominated the individual (i.e. if their nomids equal the individual's id)?

Obviously -

```
do if nomid = id. 
compute qmeangot = mean(qmean). 
execute.
```

wouldn't work, because then it would just create a variable that is identical to that participant's qmean if they somehow nominated themselves.

I can't find anything online saying how to use several participants' scores on a variable in a syntax command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by the `nomid` variable to get the `qmean` mean, then reattach the new data back to the original data, so that each participant gets the mean of nominations (if they had any).

This is to create some fake data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/id nomid (2a1) qmean (f6.2).
begin data
'a' 'b' 5.3
'b' 'a' 4.2
'c' 'a' 6.1
'd' 'b' 5.5
'e' 'c' 4.3
end data.
```

Now to do the actual task:

```
dataset name gen.
sort cases by id.
dataset declare agg.
aggregate out=agg  /break nomid /nomMean=mean(qmean). /*this created the requested calculation.
match files /file=* /table=agg/ rename nomid=id /by id. /* this attaches it back to original data.
exe.
```